# Make a Trello card disappear until its due date

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I'm using Trello as a GTD (getting things done) system and made a dashboard containing few list : Today, Next actions, Later ...

I'm used to tracks, a gtd web application which allowed me to make a card disappear until its due date. So when the due date comes, the card re-pop on my dashboard. I was using this a lot for reminders for project review, or check for people replies.

I can't find this option in Trello so I have a lot of cards in my later list and it is difficult to prioritize them. I saw the function allowing me to filter on due date but yet, this is not so handy.

Do you know if this feature is available or if is there a way to answer this need?

Answer (score 4):

Trello is a great project management tool for lightweight project management, but it lacks some sort of integrated workflow automation, so things like automatically showing a card on due date are not possible.

To work around that, I created a bot for Trello that can do exactly what you want (and a lot more). It's been running for a while with very satisfied users (see this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/trello/comments/4f9sdn/a_butler_bot_for_trello/)).

To use it, you invite user "butlerbot" to your board. It will create a list called "Butler" automatically. You enter commands as cards in that list.

The command you want is something like:

**on a card's due date, unarchive it**

Then, you just archive the cards you want to disappear and they'll magically reappear on their due date.

You can also specify a time to make them appear, e.g.:

**on a card's due date at 8am, unarchive it**

(You may want to set your timezone if you're not in US eastern time, there's a simple command for that too.)

Archiving and unarchiving is not the only way to achieve what you want. Some users prefer to have their cards in different lists and issue a command such as:

**two days before a card is due, move it to list "Tasks Due Soon"**

If you need help using it, there's a public [Trello board](https://trello.com/b/2dLsEE9t/butlerbot-for-trello). The developer (that would be me) is very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to offer a simple solution here with no coding required.  This was one feature I really wanted. I realized that you can get a unique email address for each board (see Trellos documentation).  I also use boomerang in my email (Gmail) and it allows to send emails at later times.

So I setup the email address via Trello to land in my "to do" list and then I can email it to send when I want it to appear.  Subject line of email is card name and email body is the description.  You can even add labels and attachments.

There are other programs and add ins like boomerang.  For productivity folks I recommend it highly, but anything will work for this.